# Apache Superset - Show Serial numbers for a Table chart

Tags: visualization, apache-superset

In one of our table charts we are querying DISTINCT name to show the unique students in the attendance report.

Is there anything we can do to show ascending serial numbers next to the name similar to the below image.

[Serial Numbers for Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a71Pn.png)

We have tried some queries with RANK and ROW_NUMBER window functions however due to distinct we are not able to get consecutive numbers.